# How can I play a locally saved file in the emulator?

Tags: android, text-to-speech, android-mediaplayer

I am implementing an application which used to play an audio file (output from Text to speech and stored in `mnt/sdcard/audiofiles/audio.mp3`). When I try to play this using MediaPlayer I get an error.

Code:

```
MediaPlayer  mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
try {
  mMediaPlayer.setDataSource("/mnt/sdcard/audiofiles/audio01.mp3");
  mMediaPlayer.prepare();
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
mMediaPlayer.start();
```

**Error:**

> ```
>   02-05 13:11:40.859: I/SynthProxy(286): setting pitch to 100<br>
> ```

```
  02-05 13:11:40.898: E/MediaPlayer(15651): error (1, -2147483648)<br>
  02-05 13:11:40.898: W/System.err(15651): java.io.IOException: Prepare failed.: status=0x1<br>
  02-05 13:11:40.898: W/System.err(15651):  at android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(Native Method)<br>
  02-05 13:11:40.898: W/System.err(15651):  at com.example.testmedai1.MainActivity$MySpeech.onInit(MainActivity.java:93)<br>
  02-05 13:11:40.898: W/System.err(15651):  at android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech$1.onServiceConnected(TextToSpeech.java:451)<br>
  02-05 13:11:40.898: W/System.err(15651):  at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ServiceDispatcher.doConnected(ActivityThread.java:1247)<br>
  02-05 13:11:40.898: W/System.err(15651):  at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo$ServiceDispatcher$RunConnection.run(ActivityThread.java:1264)<br>
  02-05 13:11:40.898: W/System.err(15651):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)<br>
  02-05 13:11:40.898: W/System.err(15651):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)<br>
  02-05 13:11:40.898: W/System.err(15651):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)<br>
  02-05 13:11:40.898: W/System.err(15651):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)<br>
  02-05 13:11:40.898: W/System.err(15651):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)<br>
  02-05 13:11:40.898: W/System.err(15651):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)<br>
  02-05 13:11:40.898: W/System.err(15651):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)<br>
  02-05 13:11:40.898: W/System.err(15651):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)<br>
  02-05 13:11:40.898: W/System.err(15651):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)<br>
  02-05 13:11:40.898: E/MediaPlayer(15651): start called in state 0<br>
  02-05 13:11:40.898: E/MediaPlayer(15651): error (-38, 0)<br>
  02-05 13:11:40.918: E/MediaPlayer(15651): Error (-38,0)<br>
```

**Edit 1:**

This is the total code I am trying, When button1 clicked I creating an audio file. I checked for the file using DDMS->File Exploring and saved it to my desktop and played. It is working fine. But when I try to access it pragmatically and try to play I got the error.

```
 package com.example.testmedai1;

 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileInputStream;
 import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.HashMap;


 import android.media.MediaPlayer;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.os.Environment;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
 import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.EditText;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button store, play;
EditText input;
String speakTextTxt;
TextToSpeech mTts;
private String path;
HashMap<String, String> myHashRender = new HashMap<String, String>();
String tempDestFile ;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    store = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    store.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()  {

        public void onClick(View v) {
          
            
            speakTextTxt = "Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world";
            HashMap<String, String> myHashRender = new HashMap<String, String>();
            myHashRender.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, speakTextTxt);

            String exStoragePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
            Log.d("MainActivity", "exStoragePath : "+exStoragePath);
            File appTmpPath = new File(exStoragePath + "/audiofiles/");
            boolean isDirectoryCreated = appTmpPath.mkdirs();
            Log.d("MainActivity", "directory "+appTmpPath+" is created : "+isDirectoryCreated);
            String tempFilename = "audio01.mp3";
            tempDestFile = appTmpPath.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + tempFilename;
            Log.d("MainActivity", "tempDestFile : "+tempDestFile);
            new MySpeech(speakTextTxt);
        }
    });
}

class MySpeech implements OnInitListener
{

            String tts;

    public MySpeech(String tts)
    {
        this.tts = tts;
        mTts = new TextToSpeech(MainActivity.this, this);
    }

    public void onInit(int status) 
    {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "onInit() called");
        
        int i = mTts.synthesizeToFile(speakTextTxt, myHashRender, tempDestFile);
        if(i == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS)
        {
                                              
          Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Saved "+i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
          toast.show();   
          
        path = "/mnt/sdcard/audiofiles/audio01.mp3";
     
        //FileInputStream fis;
        
         
        MediaPlayer  mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            //fis = new FileInputStream();
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource("/mnt/sdcard/audiofiles/audio01.mp3");
            mMediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        mMediaPlayer.start();
        }
        else {
            Log.v("MainActivity", "error saving wav file : "+i);
        }
    }
  }
 
}
```

**Edit2:**

I tried with the following code, still I am getting same error.

```
class MySpeech implements OnInitListener
{

            String tts;

    public MySpeech(String tts)
    {
        this.tts = tts;
        mTts = new TextToSpeech(MainActivity.this, this);
    }

    public void onInit(int status) 
    {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "onInit() called");
        
        int i = mTts.synthesizeToFile(speakTextTxt, myHashRender, tempDestFile);
        if(i == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS)
        {
                                              
          Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Saved "+i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
          toast.show();   
          
        try 
        {
            audioPlayer("mnt/sdcard/audiofiles" , "audio01.mp3");  // your file location
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 


            
        }
        else {
            Log.v("MainActivity", "error saving wav file : "+i);
        }
    }
  }

 public void audioPlayer(String path, String fileName) throws IOException
 {        
        if (mp != null) 
        {   System.out.println("before mp.reset() ");
               mp.reset();     
               System.out.println("after mp.reset() ");
          }

        try 
        {
            System.out.println("after path fileName ");
            mp.setDataSource(path+"/"+fileName);
            System.out.println("after path fileName ");
        } 
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            //mp.reset();
            System.out.println("IllegalArgumentException ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IllegalStateException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("IllegalStateException ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("IOException ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try 
        {
            mp.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            System.out.println("On prepare ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }  
        System.out.println("Before starting");
        mp.start();
       
      
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out playing your file using the below method.

> ```
>  public class MainActivity extends Activity {
>     Button store, play;
>     EditText input;
>     String speakTextTxt;
>     TextToSpeech mTts;
>     private String path;
>     HashMap<String, String> myHashRender = new HashMap<String, String>();
>     String tempDestFile;
>     MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;
> @Override
> public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
>     store = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
>     play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
>     input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
>     mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
>     store.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
>         public void onClick(View v) {
>             speakTextTxt = "Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world Hello world";
>             HashMap<String, String> myHashRender = new HashMap<String, String>();
>             myHashRender.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID,
>                     speakTextTxt);
>             String exStoragePath = Environment  .getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
>             Log.d("MainActivity", "exStoragePath : " + exStoragePath);
>             File appTmpPath = new File(exStoragePath + "/audiofiles/");
>             boolean isDirectoryCreated = appTmpPath.mkdirs();
>             Log.d("MainActivity", "directory " + appTmpPath
>                     + " is created : " + isDirectoryCreated);
>             String tempFilename = "audio01.mp3";
>             tempDestFile = appTmpPath.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator
>                     + tempFilename;
>             Log.d("MainActivity", "tempDestFile : " + tempDestFile); 
>              try {
>                     audioPlayer(exStoragePath ,tempFilename);  // your file location
>                 } catch (IOException e) {
>                     // TODO Auto-generated catch block
>                     e.printStackTrace();
>             } 
>         }
>     });
> }
> public void audioPlayer(String path, String fileName) throws IOException {
>     if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
>         mMediaPlayer.reset();
>     }
>     try {
>         mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(path + "/" + fileName);
>     } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
>         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
>         // mp.reset();
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
>         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     } catch (IOException e) {
>         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
>         e.printStackTrace();
>     }
> }
>  }
> ```

**EDITED:**
Check the Link [HERE](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/android-text-to-speech-implementing-pause-and-resume-in-tts-using-mediaplayer/) it will guide you for how to implement Text to Speech – Implementing pause and resume in TTS using MediaPlayer .

I hope it will help you..

Thanks.

Comment: Still I am geting the same error, I posted my total code in the Edit1: please take a look into that.

Comment: Have you tried using my code ? I have also tested your code. Its working fine from my side it doesn't show any error.

Comment: Did my code working at you end? Please confirm. Also I tried with your code still I am getting the same problem. I added my code after modifying it as you suggested (please refer Edit2).

Comment: Can you please let me know for playing the media file why are you trying to use the Text to Speech service ? Its really a very bad practice to play the media file on the TTS service method.

Comment: Don't try to initialize the mediaplayer in `onInit` method please. Just keep it simple and try to call my method onClick of button it will work definitely.

Comment: As per my requirements I need to generate an audio file and play that. That is the reason I used TTS. And I removed intialization from onInIt. Now I got null pointer exception.

Comment: Check out my code and try with it. It does not throw any error.

Comment: It won't work for me. Before playing it I need to generate the mp3 file using MySpeech subclass. Looks like you are not generating it. Please suggest me if I am wrong

Comment: I am using, Android 2.1 sdk.

Comment: Check the link which i have mentioned in my updated answer in EDITED part. You will get whatever you want. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hope you given read write permission in manifest file, if not then give it and have look below example,It will help you.

[Play mp3 in SD Card, using Android's MediaPlayer](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/07/play-mp3-in-sd-card-using-androids.html)

Comment: I went through that and there is no difference between my implementation and that. I posted all my code in the Edit1. Please have a look into that and advice me.